# perl how to access func when the module is imported on the fly

Tags: perl, function, module, require

I have a module which looks like this:

```
package Test;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub hello {
    my $val = shift
    print "val = $val\n";
}
```

and in another module I insert this one like this:

```
my $module = 'Test'
eval "require $module";
```

How can I call the function hello in the second module /I mean like a function not like a method/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a symbolic reference:

```
{
    no strict 'refs';   # disable strictures for the enclosing block
    &{ $module . '::hello' };
}
```

Alternatively, you can export the function to the calling package (see [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html)):

```
package Test;
use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT = qw(hello);

sub hello {
...
}
```

Then in your code:

```
my $module = 'Test'
eval "use $module";
hello("test");
```

Comment: In the last case the `eval` has to change to a) `use` instead of `require` or b) `import` must be called manually. At least I think so...

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
$module->can('hello')->('test');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same eval in this purposes:

```
my $module = 'Test'
eval "require $module";

eval $module . "::hello()";
```

Also you can access symbol table and get reference to code of required sub:

```
my $code = do { no strict 'refs'; \&{ $module . '::hello' } };
$code->();
```

But this doesn't looks so clean.

However, if you need method-like call on package name, you can use just:

```
$module->new();
```

This also can be useful

Comment: I'll take the second snippet over this usage of `eval EXPR` any day.